# Use of undeclared identifier UNWIND_ARM64_MODE_FRAME_OLD in plcrashreporter in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plcrashreporter

I want to integrate `plcrashreporter` to my app and when I run the `plcrashreporter`, it always gives an error:

```
use of undefined identifier UNWIND_ARM64_MODE_FRAME_OLD
```

Is it possible to fix or should I download another version of `plcrashreporter`. I am using Xcode 6.1. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove reference to (unsupported, never used by Apple) UNWIND_ARM64_MODE_FRAME_OLD.

This constant was removed in recent 10.10 / iOS 8 SDKs; the frame mode was never supported by PLCrashReporter, and as far as I'm aware, never used in externally shipping iOS/ARM64 binaries.

You can checkout this https://opensource.plausible.coop/src/projects/PLCR/repos/plcrashreporter/commits/0668f3c615d6cc6268e29adb58c9b7abd76627f5